# Python: using zip() to unpack a superlist of lists into separate lists

Tags: python, list, zip

I have a list of sublists that looks like `[Name, Week1, Week2, Week3]`

I want to create two separate lists. One is a list of all the "Name"s. Another one is a super list which each sublist is just `[Week1, Week2, Week3]`

I want to do this without using any explicit loops so I tried to use `zip(*super_list)` but I'm lost from here.

Thank you any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output, along with what you have tried and how it went wrong.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a suitable problem for `zip`: `zip` can be used to *rotate matrices* but it doesn't do arbitrary filtering or transformations. And I second the request for a more complete input set, as given the problem is extremely vague.

Answer (score 1):

Given a setup as follows:

```
Name = ['a']
Week1 = [1]
Week2 = [1, 2]
Week3 = [1, 2, 3]
temp = [Name, Week1, Week2, Week3]
```

You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
names, *weeks = temp
```

Output:

```
print(names) #['a']
print(weeks) #[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slicing:

```
names = full_list[0]
weeks = full_list[1:]
```